# Weird bug on my javascript showhide code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I got this show all thing succesfully done, but now when I click Show all and then click the text or image that opens, it puts the text below to right side of the screen.
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2tSd/2/)
[Gyazo](http://gyazo.com/59144b5ccbdd3fc47ca2072bcc1b121d)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {   
    $('.toggle-all').click(function() {
        $('.printer').each(function () {
            $(this).siblings('.gwinfo').slideToggle('slow');
        });
    });
});
</script>
<style>
.gwinfo {
    display: none;
}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
   .left{
          display: block;
          float:left; 
          width:10%;
    }
</style>
```

General: Rest of code in JSFiddle, feel free to fix some of my code, I would appreciate that a lot. Also if you manage to fix my code, please post a JSFiddle link with fixed code. Thank you a ton, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the break tag to clear your floats, use a div.  I also fixed some tags that were not properly nested.

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z2tSd/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
Guess the tags are mis-matched.. Can you change your HTML to the one as below:

<div class="gwshowhide">
        <li><a class="printer">Money Printer</a>
            <div class="gwinfo">Level Requirement: 1
                <br>Price: $1000
                <br>Production:
                <br>
                <img src="images/shop/Amber Money Printer.png">
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>

The existing one's are like where <li> tags are mismatching:
<div class="left">
    <div class="gwshowhide">
        <li><a class="printer">Money Silo</a>

            <div class="gwinfo">Level Requirement: 85
                <br>Price: $10,000
                <br>Production:
                <br>
                <img src="images/shop/Diamond Money Silo.png">
            </div>
    </div>
    </li>
</div>

Not sure if this will fix your issue though.. but you can give a try..

Also make sure you are suppressing the bullet list items using the style below:

.gwshowhide {
    list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: This made the code more clear, but didn't fix my problem. Thank you too!